# Missing Source code of a published ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a web application that is published and working in server. I have **aspx** files, but I don't have **.vb** files. I need to edit a singe page in the application. How can I reach to the **.vb** files ? or better to say that how can I edit the part that I want in the application?

**Edit:** 
Here is my aspx file:

```
<%@ page language="VB" autoeventwireup="false" inherits="UrunRapor, App_Web_hfev-r-q" %>
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v8.3, Version=8.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5377c8e3b72b4073" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" tagprefix="dxwgv" %><%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v8.3, Version=8.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5377c8e3b72b4073" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" tagprefix="dxwgv" %>
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v8.3, Version=8.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5377c8e3b72b4073" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" tagprefix="dxe" %>
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v8.3.Export, Version=8.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5377c8e3b72b4073" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.Export" tagprefix="dxwgv" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ürün Detaylı Rapor</title>
    <script language="javascript">
            window.moveTo(0, 0);
            window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
        </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table style="font-size: 9pt; width: 474px; font-family: Calibri">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px; height: 22px">
                    Ay</td>
                <td style="width: 100px; height: 22px">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboMonth" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFC0" Font-Bold="True"
                        Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="9pt">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="%%">[..]</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">January</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">February</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">March</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">April</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="05">May</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="06">June</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="07">July</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="08">August</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="09">September</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="10">October</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="11">November</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="12">December</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList></td>
                <td style="width: 100px; height: 22px">
                    Yıl
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100px; height: 22px">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboYear" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFC0" Font-Bold="True"
                        Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="9pt">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="%%">[..]</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2007">2007</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2008">2008</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2009">2009</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2010">2010</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2011</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2012</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2013</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2014</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2015</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList></td>
                <td style="width: 100px; height: 22px">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="9pt"
                        Text="Sorgula" /></td>
                <td style="width: 100px; height: 22px">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="9pt"
                        Text="Excel'e aktar" /></td>
                <td style="width: 100px; height: 22px">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="9pt"
                        Text="PDF dosyasına aktar" Width="123px" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CRRConnectionString %>">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cboMonth" Name="Month" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cboYear" Name="Year" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <dxwgv:aspxgridview id="dgCRR" runat="server" datasourceid="SqlDataSource1">
<Settings ShowFilterRow="True" ShowFilterRowMenu="True" ShowFilterBar="Visible" 
                ShowGroupedColumns="True" ShowGroupPanel="True"></Settings>

<SettingsPager Visible="False" PageSize="1000" Position="TopAndBottom"></SettingsPager>
</dxwgv:aspxgridview>
        <dxwgv:ASPxGridViewExporter ID="ToExcel" runat="server">
        </dxwgv:ASPxGridViewExporter>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Her is my .vb file which I want to use

```
Imports System.Globalization
Partial Class UrunRapor
    Inherits CRR.RequestBase
    Dim SelCmd As String
    Dim MyUser As String
    Dim dtreg As Data.DataTable

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        MyUser = Request.ServerVariables.Get("LOGON_USER")
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            Dim dareg As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
            dareg.SelectCommand = select_User(Request.ServerVariables.Get("LOGON_USER"))
            dareg.SelectCommand.Connection = cnn
            dtreg = New Data.DataTable
            dareg.Fill(dtreg)
            If dtreg.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                Response.Redirect("NotAuthRep.aspx")
            End If
            'Exit Sub
            'dgCRR.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        FillGrid()
    End Sub


    Protected Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        FillGrid()
        ToExcel.FileName = "CRR-Product.pdf"
        ToExcel.WritePdfToResponse("CRR-Product.pdf")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'ToExcel.FileName = "CRRNew"
        'ToExcel.DataBind()
        FillGrid()
        ToExcel.GridViewID = "dgCRR"
        ToExcel.WriteXlsToResponse()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub FillGrid()
        SelCmd = "SELECT  tblCRRProductDetails.CRRId, tblCRRProductDetails.ProductCode, tblCRRProductDetails.ProductName, tblCRRProductDetails.Batch, tblCRRProductDetails.ExpireDate, tblCRRProductDetails.Qty, tblCRRProductDetails.SalesUnit, tblCRR.CrrCaptureDate, tblCRR.RegistrarName, tblCRR.CustomerCode, tblCRR.CustomerName, tblCRR.Channel, tblCRR.ClaimerName, tblCRR.ClaimerAddress, tblCRR.ClaimerPhone, tblCRR.ClaimerMail, tblCRR.CaseDetails, tblCRR.RsDeptName, tblCRR.ReasonName, tblCRR.RsPerName, tblCRR.ExpecRsDay, tblCRR.ExpecRsDate, tblCRR.RsDescription, tblCRR.ResolutionDate, tblCRR.ClaimResult, tblCRR.ActionPlan, tblCRR.ClosedPerName, tblCRR.ClosingDate,tblCRR.Status FROM tblCRRProductDetails INNER JOIN tblCRR ON tblCRRProductDetails.CRRId = tblCRR.CrrID WHERE (MONTH(CrrReceiveDate) LIKE '" & cboMonth.SelectedItem.Value & "') AND (YEAR(CrrReceiveDate) LIKE '" & cboYear.SelectedItem.Value & "')"
        SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "My Connection String"
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = SelCmd
        dgCRR.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

When you publish the site, the compiled version is published on the server, not the code files.  You would need Disassembler / Decompiler to decompile the dll files. Some of them are

1. [.Net Reflecter](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)
2. [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) *(Free)*
3. [Dot Peek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) *(Free)*

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is change the ASPX, so for example instead of this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.MyPage" %>
```

You could change it like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="MyOtherNamespace.MyNewPage" %>
```

Write the new behavior in a new MyOtherNamespace.MyNewPage class (that should derive at least from System.Web.UI.Page)  that you can put in any .DLL assembly that you deploy in the `bin` directory.

You can also derive this new class from the original page (just reference the original assembly) instead of just deriving from System.Web.UI.Page, if deriving is an option for you, depending on the changes you need to do.

Otherwise, you will have to reconstruct the original code using a tool such as .NET Reflector or ILSpy to build this new class, but at least, you don't have to touch the existing compiled assembly.

Comment: I believe this will lead to a good solution but I am having difficulties implementing it. I have edited my question and add my aspx file. I have also added the code which I want this aspx page to use. Can you guide me through that?

Comment: What difficulties? PS: don't forget the namespace in the Page declare 'Inherits' attribute.

Comment: My aspx file is like that above: inherits="UrunRapor, App_Web_hfev-r-q", should I change it to inherits="NewVersionUrunRapor, App_Web_hfev-r-q", then should I do modify my vb code like that (Partial Class UrunRapor, to Partial Class NewVersionUrunRapor), Also this part I also didn't get (you can put in any .DLL assembly that you deploy in the bin directory), I am not sure how to do it too.

Comment: Create a new assembly (or use an existing one that you control), put your class in it, compile it and copy it in the bin directory (not needed if it's an assembly you control and is already there), then change the aspx for the 'inherits' attribute to point to the namespace of this new class. Don't put the assembly qualified name in the 'inherits' attribute, only the namespace+name. the ASP.NET type resolver is smart enough to find the assembly by itself if it has the full type name.

Answer (score 0):

You could try disassembling it using `ilasm` and editing the IL directly, but I think realistically you will struggle to make any changes without the source. The .cs files are the source files. Only the compiled IL files will be available on the published site. You will need to find out who published it and speak to them about getting the source.